# Proving a triangle is an isosceles triangle.

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

Suppose we have

> $\sin(A-B) + \sin(B-C)+\sin(C-A)=0$

I want to show that this is an isosceles triangle. I know I should expand this expression to something like $(\sin(A)-\sin(B))(\sin(B)-\sin(C))(\sin(C)-\sin(A))$ so that we have A=B or B=C or A=C or both. However, I cannot come up with a solution.

Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: **Hint** $$2S(\frac{a+b}{2})C(\frac{a+c-2b}{2}) + S(\frac{c-a}{2})$$
$$a+c-2b = 180-3b$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any (odd) sum of sines can be represented as a product of sines, using the formulas

$$\sin x+\sin y=2\sin\frac{x+y}{2}\cos\frac{x-y}{2}$$
and
$$\sin x=2\sin \frac{x}{2}\cos\frac{x}{2}$$ we have

$$\sin(A-B)+\sin(B-C)+\sin(C-A)$$
$$=2\sin\frac{A-B}{2}\cos\frac{A-B}{2}+2\sin \frac{B-A}{2}\cos (\frac{A+B}{2}-C)$$
$$=2\sin\frac{A-B}{2}[\cos\frac{A-B}{2}-\cos (\frac{A+B}{2}-C)]$$

And now using the formula

$$\cos x-\cos y =2\sin\frac{x+y}{2}\sin\frac{y-x}{2}$$ we have

$$=4\sin\frac{A-B}{2}\sin\frac{A-C}{2}\sin \frac{B-C}{2}$$

So we have the formula,
$$\sin(A-B)+\sin(B-C)+\sin(C-A)$$
$$=-
4\sin\frac{A-B}{2}\sin\frac{B-C}{2}\sin \frac{C-A}{2}$$

The problem is now easy, if
$$\sin(A-B)+\sin(B-C)+\sin(C-A)=0$$ then one factor of the product must be zero. Say
$$\sin\frac{A-B}{2}=0$$ and so
$$\frac{A-B}{2}=n\pi$$ and
and since you are assuming the angles are acute, the the only solution is $A=B$.

Comment: Just got the answer as I see your solution, thanks!

Comment: @Edi Great Job !

Answer (score 1):

**Hints**:

Use these facts

- $A+B+C = 180^{\circ}$
- $\sin x +\sin y = 2\sin{x+y\over 2}\cos{x-y\over 2}$
- $\sin (2x) =2\sin x \cdot \cos x$

Comment: Should I use the second formula directly to the equation?

Comment: I would use it only for first and second term. And then some double angle formula...

Comment: Yep, I used it for the first and second term and got it!